# Issue with PayTm Gateway Integration + CheckSum

Tags: java, android, checksum, paytm

Anyone help me to integrate Paytm Gateway with Android Application.
I referred many tutorials. little bit confusing.

1. I am using Android + java language.
2. I dont have any Web Server with me (Many tutorials i have seen as checksum can be generated only in Client (My Own) Web Server)
3. And also i am came to know in Paytm page checksum can be generated by using below,

https://developer.paytm.com/docs/v1/android-sdk

String paytmChecksum = CheckSumServiceHelper.getCheckSumServiceHelper().genrateCheckSum(merchantKey, paytmParams);

But they havent given any information what jar needs to imported for this.

4. Please give me some links are referral page where can i get the above information.

Comment: This may be helpful to you https://gist.github.com/pavi2410/62cb3022c3696111487256045adaaf58

Comment: @Pavitra : Thanks for the reply. Your are passing checksum in your method. My question, how to generate checksum? what jar needs to be added for the above block?